# Reading Arguments From Java Options setup in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, properties

Apache tomcat is running as a windows service on my machine and have added the properties as below,

1. Run Tomcat9w.exe.
2. Go to Java tab and add the properties under Java Options
3. Click Apply

Tomcat service is running fine and deployed application able to establish the connection to the database.

[image]

Now I want to read these properties in the java code. Do anyone know how to read these properties?

Any guidance or directions will definitely help

Comment: Call [`System.getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--) to get the classpath (`java.class.path`) and all the `-D` options. --- To print them sorted, use: `System.getProperties().keySet().stream().map(Object::toString).sorted().forEach(k -> System.out.println(k + " = " + System.getProperty(k)));`

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, but this won't give you the details added in the Java Options under Java tab. This gives you just system properties, not Tomcat

Comment: I am still not getting any further details. Could anyone help with this, please?

Comment: What further detail are you wanting? All the `-D` values in the `Java Options` field will be available in the `System.getProperties()` result (without the `-D` itself).

Comment: @Andreas: I don't see the values in the System.getProperties(). I made sure service is up and running, still don't see.So only asked for any other ways to get the properties.

Comment: Really? You don't see e.g. `catalina.home` at all in the running Tomcat code? I don't think Tomcat can even function without that.